# My android app is crashing in most devices

Tags: java, android, android-studio, exception, android-debug

The android app I had created is not crashing in the emulator nor the phone I am using but shows some exceptions like java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:  in the logcat, but when I transfer the apk file to other devices then 80% of the users reported the app got crashed while just opening the app or opening an activity with on the app.

This is driving me crazy I tested this on different emulators and none of them got crashed.I just couldn't understand what the problem is please help.

MY **AndroidMaifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.androgeekzz.pokemongo_bestguidetipsandtricks">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Basics" />
    <activity android:name=".Tips" />
    <activity android:name=".Tricks" />
    <activity android:name=".Bas_What" />
    <activity android:name=".Bas_Downld" />
    <activity android:name=".Bas_Pikatchu" />
    <activity android:name=".Bas_PokeCapture" />
    <activity android:name=".Bas_LVI5" />
    <activity android:name=".Bas_GainXP_LVL_Up" />
    <activity android:name=".Bas_All_Iteams" />
    <activity android:name=".Bas_All_Places" />
    <activity android:name=".Advanced" />
    <activity android:name=".Adv_gainXP" />
    <activity android:name=".Adv_1candies" />
    <activity android:name=".Adv_2Evolution" />
    <activity android:name=".Adv_3PowerUp" />
    <activity android:name=".Adv_4FightAGym" />
    <activity android:name=".Adv_5DefendGym" />
    <activity android:name=".Adv_6LvlGym" />
    <activity android:name=".Adv_7Type" />
    <activity android:name=".Adv_8Egg" />
    <activity android:name=".Tips_0Good" />
    <activity android:name=".Tips_1Eevee" />
    <activity android:name=".Tips_2EarnXP" />
    <activity android:name=".Tips_3Find" />
    <activity android:name=".Tips_4Nest" />
    <activity android:name=".Adv_Nests" />
    <activity android:name=".Resources"></activity>
</application>
```

**Main Activity:**

```
package com.androgeekzz.pokemongo_bestguidetipsandtricks;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        int times = prefs.getInt("ok_clicked", 0);

        if (times == 0) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setTitle("Hi there user").setMessage("This app version right now is just 1.0 the later versions will be released soon with even more content,Images and in app video tutorials etc..and this app is completely ADD free so please do consider rating it. ").setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    editor.putInt("ok_clicked", 1);
                    editor.apply();

                }
            }).show();
        }

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    }

    public void basicsOnclick(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Basics.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }

    public void advanceOnclick(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Advanced.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }

    public void tipsOnclick(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Tips.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }

    public void tricksOnclick(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Tricks.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }

    public void resourceLinksOnclick(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Resources.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }

    public void aboutOnclick(View view) {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setTitle("About").setMessage("App Name    :Pokemon GO-Guide\nVersion        :1.0 \nCreator        :Prudhvi").setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
        }).show();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            this.finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

**LogCat** (It had not crashed for this log cat)-

```
at com.android.systemui.statusbar.SignalClusterView.apply(SignalClusterView.java:468)
at com.android.systemui.statusbar.policy.NetworkControllerImpl.refreshViews(NetworkControllerImpl.java:1986)
at com.android.systemui.statusbar.policy.NetworkControllerImpl.refreshViews(NetworkControllerImpl.java:1679)
at com.android.systemui.statusbar.policy.NetworkControllerImpl.onReceive(NetworkControllerImpl.java:643)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:895)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:810)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:114)
08-07 23:23:38.730 824-824/?

E/Xposed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mediatek.systemui.ext.DefaultStatusBarPlugin#getDataNetworkTypeIconGemini(com.mediatek.systemui.ext.NetworkType,int)#exact
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedHelpers.findMethodExact(XposedHelpers.java:170)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod(XposedHelpers.java:131)
at com.ceco.lollipop.gravitybox.ModStatusBar$24.afterHookedMethod(ModStatusBar.java:1072)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:689)
at com.mediatek.systemui.ext.PluginFactory.getStatusBarPlugin(<Xposed>)
at com.android.systemui.statusbar.SignalClusterView.apply(SignalClusterView.java:401)
at com.android.systemui.statusbar.policy.NetworkControllerImpl.refreshViews(NetworkControllerImpl.java:1986)
at com.android.systemui.statusbar.policy.NetworkControllerImpl.refreshViews(NetworkControllerImpl.java:1679)
at com.android.systemui.statusbar.policy.NetworkControllerImpl.onReceive(NetworkControllerImpl.java:643)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:895)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:810)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:114)
08-07 23:23:38.731 824-824/? 

E/Xposed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mediatek.systemui.ext.DefaultStatusBarPlugin#getDataNetworkTypeIconGemini(com.mediatek.systemui.ext.NetworkType,int)#exact
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedHelpers.findMethodExact(XposedHelpers.java:170)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod(XposedHelpers.java:131)
at com.ceco.lollipop.gravitybox.ModStatusBar$24.afterHookedMethod(ModStatusBar.java:1072)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:689)
at com.mediatek.systemui.ext.PluginFactory.getStatusBarPlugin(<Xposed>)
at com.android.systemui.statusbar.SignalClusterView.getNullIconIdGemini(SignalClusterView.java:557)
at com.android.systemui.statusbar.SignalClusterView.apply(SignalClusterView.java:468)
at com.android.systemui.statusbar.policy.NetworkControllerImpl.refreshViews(NetworkControllerImpl.java:1986)
at com.android.systemui.statusbar.policy.NetworkControllerImpl.refreshViews(NetworkControllerImpl.java:1679)
at com.android.systemui.statusbar.policy.NetworkControllerImpl.onReceive(NetworkControllerImpl.java:643)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:895)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:810)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:114)
```

Comment: if you are testing on devices running **Android 6.0 (API level 23)**. you should implement [Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).for more details read this [post](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en).

Comment: @skydroid thanks for your replay but i had tried this across all the android versions and the problem persists across all versions and it's randomly working in some devices and working in all the emulators.The logcat is also different across all versions if not all devices(I had not tested in the same version on the other device).

Comment: Have you checked the answer to this issue: https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/issues/55

Comment: i havn't used any complicate programming or any thing related to xposed installer or busy box in the app just consists of lists and with some string text description etc..

Comment: did you find a solution yet?